# Hubble mirrors shape

Tags: optics, telescopes

The Hubble mirrors are two hyperbolas.
I see on Wiki the formulas for the Ritchey–Chrétien telescope.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ritchey%E2%80%93Chr%C3%A9tien_telescope

My question is how is the shape of the hubble mirrors calculated?